# How to make this Javascript appear in a different way?

Tags: javascript

So what I want to do is have the code below be shown in a different way. For example when it says 0.135731974 I want it to really say 13.5731974%, but still count up at the same pace. If you know what I mean could you Please show me how!

Here is code:

```
 <script>

 var timer;
 var stop;

 function startCount()
 {
      stop = false;
      timer = setInterval(count,1);
 }
 function stopCount()
 {
      stop = true;
 }
 function count()
 {
      if(stop == false)
          {
           var el = document.getElementById('counter');
           var currentNumber = parseFloat(el.innerHTML);
           el.innerHTML = currentNumber+0.00000003831417624521;
      }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="counter">0</div>

 <input type="button" value="reset" id="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 0;" />
 <input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="startCount();" />
 <input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" onclick="stopCount();" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `count()` function to this:

```
var currentNumber = 0;
function count() {
    if (!stop) {
        var el = document.getElementById('counter');
        currentNumber += 0.00000003831417624521;
        el.innerHTML = (currentNumber * 100) + "%";
    }
}
```

It much easier and more efficient to just keep the `currentNumber` in a variable rather than parsing it out of the HTML each time, especially after you've formatted it as a percent value.

Also, your `stopCount()` function needs to be this so you don't get multiple timers running at once:

```
function stopCount() {
    stop = true;
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

The whole code block could be simplified and cleaned up to be this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
var timer, currentNumber = 0;

function startCount() {
    if (!timer) {      
        timer = setInterval(count, 100);
    }
}

function stopCount() {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = null;
    }
}

function count() {
    var el = document.getElementById('counter');
    currentNumber += 0.00000003831417624521;
    el.innerHTML = (currentNumber * 100) + "%";
}

function reset() {
    currentNumber = 0;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = "0";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="counter">0</div>

<input type="button" value="reset" id="reset" onclick="reset()" />
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="startCount();" />
<input type="button" value="stop" id="stop" onclick="stopCount();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, now it freezes at 0.0000038314176245210005%

Comment: @user1200940 - I've corrected that issue and cleaned up the rest of the code.  Are you sure you really want this running every single millisecond?

Comment: Now it wont start :/ sorry im such a noob at it, could you try and just give me the whole code that I could use.

Comment: And it doesnt have to run every millisecond, I just want it to be in a  0.00% format as its still going up the same amount

Comment: THanks! But it still freezes :/ I am going to just have to go with what I got!

Comment: @user1200940 - I've included the whole code and fixed one more typo.

Comment: @user1200940 - since you're new here on stackoverflow, do you realize that you're supposed to pick the answer that helped you the most as the best answer.  You click the checkmark to the upper left of the answer (it will turn green).  That also rewards those who have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `%` directly in the HTML, and up your incrementation value by a factor of 100:

```html
<div><span id="counter">0</span>%</div>
```

```js
el.innerHTML = currentNumber + 0.000003831417624521;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/MJJkq/

Comment: If you could put that together with mine that would be awesome! Cause when I try it now it says "INFIN%" Thanks!

Comment: This won't work because you format the HTML into percent and then the next loop around, you do parseFloat on the percent value, not the original value.

Comment: Now it says NaN% Do you mind copying and pasting the code you used? Thanks!

Comment: @user1200940 - My original answer was a little hasty and clearly flawed.  I've changed it to something that I think makes a lot more sense.